# Slashes stripped in ACF

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields, paths

Use ACF pluging to save a windows path like this : `c:\users\thanassis\photos` using a text field. The ACF saves this : `c:usersthanassisphotos` as path except the character `\`. If I use this `/` it's ok.
I would like to know if it is possible to save the correct path?

Comment: There a discussion about this [here](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/regression-backslashes-stripped-in-wysiwyg/).

Answer (score 2):

Until this gets fixed, the only workaround I can see is to intercept the `$_POST` data and add extra slashes prior to ACF stripping them:

```
/**
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/143555/1685
 */
function wpse_143555_acf_add_slashes() {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['fields'] ) ) {
        foreach ( $_POST['fields'] as $k => $v ) {
            if ( ! is_array( $v ) )
                $_POST['fields'][ $k ] = addslashes( $v );
        }
    }   
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_143555_acf_add_slashes', 1 );
```

Currently it'll only work on text (string) fields, but I could easily change it to work on others too (not sure of the repercussions though).

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of this `$_POST['fields']`. I know that they are variables that pass by method post. Needs to replace something in my case?

Comment: What it's doing is adding extra slashes to the field data (from the ACF form) *before* ACF comes along and strips them away. Just pop the code in your theme's `functions.php` or as a plugin, and you're good to go!

Comment: This works but when I save it this I get back my text with double slashes. In DB it is correctly saved. The other thing is that I want to call this function in a specific field. Is it possible to handle $_POST?